# Double session PHP issue

Tags: php, mysql

Good evening, I am currently working on the website where there are two entities students and admins. I am attempting to have the admins have the ability to view a specific student's detail page.

I am having difficulties while attempting to have two sessions running at the same time (one would be the logged in admin, and two would be the "selected student's id" which would be saved when selected from a drop down form: and will be redirected to a "Details" page. Here is where the student information will be populated.). Any ideas into the proper way to do this would be greatly appreciated.

(I am currently thinking of adding a table to my sql and having it populated by Admin_ID as a FK student_ID as a FK, and AD_Select_ID Primary key )

i hope there is a more simple way. please advise.

thank you

## Retrieve admin name

if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['ad_loggedin'])) {

```
$q_auser    = "SELECT fName FROM admins WHERE a_id = '$_SESSION[a_id]'";

$r_auser    = mysqli_query($dbc, $q_auser);

$auser_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r_auser);
```

}

## Retrieve user data

```
$q_users   = "SELECT s_id, fName, lName, dob, email,  gender, classification FROM students ORDER BY s_id ASC";
$r_users   = mysqli_query($dbc, $q_users);
$user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r_users);
```

## Gather student ID & redirect to profile view

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_POST['profile'])) {

```
#no profile selected
if($_POST['user'] == "0") {
    
    header('Location: index.php');
    
} else {
    
    $_SESSION['st_id'] = $_POST['user'];
    header('Location: profile.php');

    
}
```

}

## body post statement:

```
      <label for="users"><h4>Select A User:</h4></label>
          
            <select name="user" class="form-control" id="user" style="width:40%;">
              <option value="0"> </option>
              <?php
                while ($user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($r_users)) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$user_data["id"].'">' .$user_data["s_id"]. " -> " .$user_data["lName"]. ", ".$user_data["fName"]. '</option>';                   
                }
               ?>
               
       
            </select>
            
            <br />
            
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="profile">View Profile</button>
```

Comment: if you need save data of several users and store it, use subarray in session, so even single user will have array in session, admin will have several (more then one) and will use "current" or "switched".

Answer (score 0):

You only ever need to have one session at a time.  You can have that session store all the data, such as the actual user and the users being emulated.  Whenever your PHP is trying to figure out who the user is, have it check the emulated user data as well.  If you want more details, you'll need to give more details about your code.

Comment: thank you for your response. I will copy both the code of the "selecting" of the emulated user, and the pulling of the data. please let me know if you can help. I am completely stuck.